# Why are does the argument ($\omega t + k z$) produce waves in the negative direction?

Tags: waves

There are a couple of ways to express a plane wave (using imaginary numbers):

1. $e^{i(\omega t - kx)} = \cos(\omega t-kx) + i\sin(\omega t-kx)$
2. $e^{i( -\omega t + kx)} = \cos( -\omega t + kx) + i\sin( -\omega t + kx)$
3. $e^{i(-\omega t - kx)} = \cos(-\omega t - kx) + i\sin(-\omega t - kx)$
4. $e^{i(\omega t + kx)}= \cos(\omega t + kx) + i\sin(\omega t + kx)$

My understanding is that points 1. and 2. represent waves traveling in the *positive* $x$-direction, while 3. and 4. represent waves traveling in the *negative* $x$-direction.

My question is then: **Why is that?** Why does having the same sign on the time and spatial terms result in a wave going *backward*? If points 1. and 2. are waves going *forward*, what is the difference between the two waves (are they equivalent, or do the expressions represent two different waves going in the positive $x$-direction)?

I guess one way to "justify" it would be to plot the waves in python, wolfram alpha, or something similar and see how they behave. However, I hope to get a somewhat *deeper* understanding of what is going on here. It would be nice to see some plots, but then I would still not understand *why* having the same sign gives a wave that travels *backward* and a different sign a wave that travels *forward*.

**Edit:** Here is a plot of $\cos(2x-3t)$ from wolfram alpha:

[image]

I found it helpful seeing this image together with Davide Dal Bosco's answer.

Comment: Compare the graph of $f(x+a)$ with that of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to drop the complex notation, as it is useful to do the computations, but at the end usually one takes only the real part to get the result.

A travelling wave can be expressed, as you correctly say as
\begin{equation}
\phi^+(x, t) \propto \cos(\omega t - k x)
\end{equation}
or as
\begin{equation}
\phi^-(x, t) \propto \cos(\omega t + k x)
\end{equation}

Assume that you want to focus on the $x$-position of the maximum of the wave at any given time. This can be of course generalized for a point at any phase in the wave.

The maximum occurs at phase equal to zero ($\cos(0)=1$).

the position of the maximum is at any time for a wave traveling towards the positive direction of the $x$-axis is
\begin{equation}
0 = \omega t - k x_{max} \longrightarrow x_{max}(t) = \frac{\omega}{k} t
\end{equation}
As both $k$ and $\omega$ are positive constants, we see that the position of the maximum is moving towards larger $x$-values with time (as we expect).

On the other hand, for a wave traveling towards the negative direction of the $x$-axis is
\begin{equation}
0 = \omega t + k x_{max} \longrightarrow x_{max}(t) = -\frac{\omega}{k} t
\end{equation}
Once again, as both $k$ and $\omega$ are positive constants, we see that the position of the maximum is decreasing with time.

Comment: Great explanation especially the formula for the maximum never occurred to me. Just wanted to add one bit, this approach makes it obvious why only the relative sign matters. Because $t$ And $\omega$ are normally positive same signs always means maximum moves left different signs means maximum moves right.

Answer (score 1):

The case you are referring to, $(\omega t+kx)$, is a special case of a more general solution.  In general, the one-dimensional wave equation may be written as
$$f(x-ct)+g(x+ct),$$ where $f$ and $g$ are arbitrary functions and $c$ is the wave speed.  Note that $kc=\omega$, so if $g(x)=kx$, you get $g(x+ct)=\omega t+kx$.

Let us just look at $g$.  As I said, these functions are arbitrary, so you can make them look like anything you want.  For the sake of this discussion, lets use the Gaussian distribution:
$$g(x) = e^{-x^2},$$
where I am not paying any attention to units (you would need to normalize the $x$ coordinate with some length scale).  Given the function, this is what the wave looks like at $t=0$.  The peak occurs at $x=0$.  Since the function does not change with time (just the wave), the peak will occur whenever the argument of $g$ is equal to zero.  Thus, the peak will always occur when $x+ct=0$.  Rearranging this equation, we find that the $x$ position of the peak at time $t$ will be at
$$x=-ct.$$
If $t$ is positive, the peak will be at some negative point.  The larger $t$ is, the farther the peak will be in the negative.  Thus, $g$ represents a left-going wave (assuming left is negative).  There was nothing special about our function; regardless of your definition of $g$, it will still be a left-going wave.

In the example above, I picked out the peak as $x+ct=0$.  In general, I could pick any number, $x+ct=\phi$, where $\phi$ is some real number.  With this definition, $\phi$ is called the *phase*.  Rearranging as above, I can write the left-going position of a particular phase at a specific time as
$x=\phi - ct$.  Regardless of what $\phi$ is, $x$ will go farther and farther to the left with increasing time.

Note that the same discussion applies to $f$, but with everything moving to the right.  Thus, any solution to the one-dimensional wave equation may be written as a combination of a right-going wave ($f$) and a left-going wave ($g$).  This representation of the solution of the wave equation is called [d'Alembert's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula).

Comment: Nice answer! It is kind of like a generalization of Davide Dal Bosco's answer.